# Java runtime exec not handling string array well

Tags: java, runtime

I have a tomcat servlet which calls a jar function with parameters. The first parameter sometimes contains space. So I tried to use a String array, but it doesn't work at all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
requestParm = "java -classpath c:\\j\\test.jar test.connect " + fileName + " new";
requestParmarray =new String[]{"java -classpath c:\\j\\test.jar test.connect ",fileName , " new"};
requestParmarrayNew =new String[]{"java -classpath c:\\j\\test.jar test.connect "+fileName+" new"};

// This line works.but can not handle space well
Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(requestPar);

// Does not call the function at all
Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(requestParmarray ); 

// Does not call the function at all
Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(requestParmarrayNew ); 

// Does not call the function at all
Process ls_proc = new ProcessBuilder("java -classpath c:\\j\\test.jar test.connect ",fileName, "new" ).start();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating the array incorrectly: Each individual argument must be in its own entry:

```
String[] requestParmArray = new String[] {
    "java",
    "-classpath",
    "c:\\j\\test.jar",
    "test.connect",
    fileName,
    "new"
};
Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(requestParmArray);
```

Also note that I removed the space you had after `test.connect`; the spaces you put on the command line are just to separate arguments, but in the above, they're separated by being separate entries in the array.

Comment: This fixes my problem :). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should make the array in `exec()` have each parameter as a separate array entry like:

```
String[] requestPar = new String[]{"java", "-classpath", "c:\\j\\test.jar", "test.connect ", fileName, "new"};
```

And use it:

```
Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(requestPar);
```

Comment: This fixes my problem. Thank you.